# The type or namespace name 'Protocol' does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I can't for the life of me get my Visual Studio 2013 MVC project to compile when I include a using statement to the nuget package for **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions**:

> The type or namespace name 'Protocol' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.IdentityModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

It might be important to note that I am using similarly-named-but-unrelated packages as follows:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;
```

I have tried updating the packages.config, Web.config, and csproj files to ensure that the versions are all the same, up to date, and the hint path is pointing to my packages folder correctly (which it is). I have also tried reinstalling it via the nuget console (Update-Package -reinstall) as well as ensured the dependency on  System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt is installed and up-to-date and still no luck.

I'm wondering if it's at all related to the usage of the other similarly named Microsoft.IdentityModel packages and Visual Studio is simply getting confused because of this, since the Extensions package does indeed exist: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions/

Excerpt from my packages.config

```
<package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions" version="1.0.2.206221351" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel" version="6.1.7600.16394" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="2.16.204221202" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="4.0.2.206221351" />
```

It should also be noted that I'm using the nuget package restore strategy via the packages.config file.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions NuGet package contains an assembly called Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions.dll but the namespaces available from this assembly are:

- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions
- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols
- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens

The above namespaces were taken from the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions.xml file that is included in the NuGet package, but you can also get them from the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/tree/master/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions).

So there is no Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions namespace in the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions NuGet package the using should be:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions;
```